# Docker Dashboard not opening

Tags: docker, dashboard

i installed docker on my laptop (windows 10) and docker is running in the background and i can do anything in docker command prompt (pull/push/build,etc); however, if i want to open the docker dashboard by right clicking the docker icon and selecting either dashboard or setting

[image]

[image: i cannot]

it won't open any docker GUI. I should normally see the following, but nothing happens on my laptop.

[image]

Is there any step missing so i can see the Docker UI?

Comment: Nothing. Try reinstalling it.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, i did uninstall/install several times and restart the laptop on each uninstall. I also manually deleted docker folders on user/AppData, ProgramData, .docker folder, but nothing has worked so far

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by 'docker command prompt'?

Comment: i mean running docker commands such as $docker run hello-world, docker pull hello-world, etc

Comment: Ok, that's a bash prompt you just showed me. How is this working in bash if you can't configure it to work in wsl through the UI? Have you installed docker in wsl with apt or a script?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, i was able to prompt the docker dashboard UI by downgrading docker to version 2.5.0.1